# Generic type constraint while implementing generic interface without constraints

Tags: generics, typescript, resharper, type-constraints, typescript1.6

my question is more about Resharper TypeScript support as you are about to find in a while.

I have such a generic interface for my repository

```
export interface IRepository<T> {
    getAll(): IPromise<T[]>;
    getItem(id: number): IPromise<T>;
    add(item: T): IPromise<T>;
    update(item: T): IPromise<T>;
    deleteItem(item: T): IPromise<T>;
}
```

and this kind of implementation below. Please notice that the generic type for the class is constrained to extend the `IIdentifyable` interface, which in turn ensures the type contains a numeric `Id` property

```
export abstract class BaseHttpRepository<T extends IIdentifyable> implements IRepository<T> {
    // ...
    add(item: T): angular.IPromise<T> {
        var url = this.getFullUrl();
        return this.httpService.post<T>(url, item);
    }
    // ...
}
```

I suppose the code is correct as the Visual Studio with TS1.6 compiles this fine. However, Resharper gets me an error that you can find below

[image: resharper typescript error]

I'm using the latest Resharper version with my VS2013 Ultimate. Is it a problem with Resharper only or is the code actually wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a problem with Resharper only or is the code actually wrong?

If you can run `tsc -p <path your tsconfig.json>` and you get *no* errors, => A resharper problem. Note that resharper has its own langauge service implementation *different* from the *official* typescript implementation.

Beyond that based on your code :

```
export interface IRepository<T> {
    add(item: T): IPromise<T>;
}
export abstract class BaseHttpRepository<T extends IIdentifyable> implements IRepository<T> {
    // ...
    add(item: T): angular.IPromise<T> {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

should be fine for `tsc`

Comment: Actually I expected an answer like this. I'm just curious about why the implementation of the language might differ while the language is official.
As I mentioned - the code compiles fine and vanilla VS notifies me of no errors when I disable Resharper. What I'm wondering is why such a difference when the code is fine. I guess I should post this on Resharper forum and cry for help! :)